# Physical meaning of rippled spectrum

Tags: filters, frequency-spectrum

What do ripples in the spectrum of a bandpass filter physically mean? What do they tell us about the filter? Please check the picture:

[image]

The filter should look smooth, like a resonator, such as

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ripples in a spectrum are an indication of echoes in time.  Specifically consider how the Fourier Transform of a sinewave is two impulses in frequency. Similarly, given the reciprocity of the Fourier Transform, a sinewave in frequency (in other words, ripples in the spectrum) is two impulses in the time domain. The Fourier Transform of the frequency response is the impulse response. A system that has an impulse response consisting of two impulses at different locations in time will output the input combined with a delayed copy of the input (echo).

In practice this can be caused by multipath delays for a signal propagating between a transmitter and receiver, reflections from poor matching on a high frequency (microwave) circuit, or other equivalent effects that result in multiple copies of the signal.

Comment: Does that mean there is information in the frequency separation of these mini peaks? If yes what is this information?

Comment: Yes that would be the inverse of the time between the signal and its echo (reflected copy which combines with the primary signal and alternates between causing constructive and destructive interference depending on frequency)

Comment: Also for the case where it is indeed only two copies of the signal, with no other noise present: if the two copies of the signal were of the same magnitude, there would be complete cancellation- or partial cancellation otherwise. Thus the depths of the nulls, or equivalently the peak to peak magnitude of the variation over frequency, is an indication of the relative strength of the two copies. (A small ripple would indicate one copy is significantly larger).